# How To Specify a Reference Method Parameter that Implements an Interface

Tags: java, events, event-handling, event-listener

I've a question just for curiosity, it's how to specify a reference parameter for a method and ensure that this parameter must implement an interface

such as ActionListener method actionPerformed when handling an event
when you add an actionListener to a GUI component using addActionListener(arg) method
arg must be a reference to an object that implements ActionListener interface
and that's my question
how addActionListener method ensures that its arg implements ActionListener interface

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField();//creating new text field

TextFieldHandler textFiledHandler = new TextFieldHandler();//object of the handler

textField.addActionListener(textFieldHandler);//here's my question
add(textField);

//creating a nested class
private class TextFieldHandler implements ActionListener {
     @Override
     public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
          //do something here
     }//end actionPerformed
}//end class TextFieldHandler
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method description of your example method is:

```
public void addActionListener(ActionListener l)
```

Therefore the only types you can pass to it are of type `ActionListener`

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#addActionListener(java.awt.event.ActionListener)

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is have the type of the parameter set to the interface name, and then the method will accept objects as long as they are of a type that implements the interface.

Example:

```
 public void methodName(InterfaceName x) {}
```

will accept as a parameter any objects that implement "InterfaceName".

In this particular case, `public void addActionListener(ActionListener l)` ensures that the argument implements the `ActionListener` interface (which is how Java does it).